# dojo floating pane change minimize/dock icon

Tags: dojo

is there a way to change dojo's floating pane minimize/dock downward arrowhead icon?

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.FloatingPane" 
id="floatingPane" data-dojo-props="resizable:false, dockable:true, title:'my floating pane', closable:false"  
style="position:absolute; top:145px; left:5px; width:565px; height:750px; z-index:3; ">
   Dojo's floating pane
</div>
```

One nice option would be to use a more standard minimize icon such as the small line found in the upper right border of a standard Windows window.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own theme (or override part of the native theme).

The CSS files associated to the FloatingPane is : "dojo/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css"

You can find some details about theming on dojo website :
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html